# differential normal cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$Let $X$ be a scheme, and $Y$ a closed subscheme; to simplify notation assume $X=\Spec(A)$
is affine, so $Y=\Spec(B)$, $B=A/I$. According to the standard definition, the normal cone to $Y$ in $X$ is $N_Y(X)=\Spec(\bar{A})$, where $\bar{A}=\bigoplus_n I^n/I^{n+1}$.

A derivation $\delta$ of $A$ sends $I^n$ to $I^{n-1}$, so it induces a derivation $\bar{\delta}$ of $\bar{A}$ of degree $(-1)$. Let $J\subset \bar{A}$ be the largest ideal
such that $J\subset  \bar{A}_+=\bigoplus_{n>0} I^n/I^{n+1}$ and $\bar{\delta}(J)\subset J$ for every $\delta\in \operatorname{Der}(A)$ (it is easy to see that $J$ is well defined).

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth varieties over a characteristic zero field then $J=0$; but if $A={\mathbb C}[x]$ and $I=(x^2)$ then $J$ has codimension 3.

The question is whether this $J$ is something people in commutative algebra or algebraic geometry have considered.